# Getting real time interval between diffrent clients interaction with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I store timestamps of interactions with clients by using `time()` in my PHP code, i want all my clients to be able to know how much time passed between the last interaction of any client with the server to current time (with no timezone offset or whatever).

I use JavaScript on the client side, and I tried using this code :

```
new Date().getTime()-new Date(interactionXML.find("time").text()*1000).getTime()
```

where `interactionXML.find("time").text()` returns the exact value that the PHP code stored (given by time()), this code outputs values with deviation of about 8 minutes...

Comment: would just sending the exact server time of the request along with it allow you to do the proper calculation?

Comment: @rooster but this must be cross many clients not just between a client and the server

Comment: Where is the PHP code storing `time()`? In a DB, a file, etc.?

Comment: on MySQL db, why is this relevant? i can deal with a deviation of a few seconds, but 8 minutes is far too much...

Comment: Was just trying to make sure you weren't doing something silly like using a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [Smartupdater](http://www.eslinstructor.net/smartupdater/) or [RealtimeAJAX](https://code.google.com/p/realtimeajax/) ?

Comment: well, Smartupdater for example will provide you exact timestamps for long polling. You just need a small php script which prints the current time/timestamp so you can fetch it via ajax